# iOS UIButton title keeps reverting in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton, interface-builder, uistoryboard

I am trying to set up a fairly simple Storyboard/Interface builder app with a`UITableViewController`, with two prototype cells.

The first prototype cell displays information on the main `UILabel` and the second prototype cell contains a`UIButton`. I have connected the button's`touchUpInside` action to some piece of code where I want to execute stuff and modify the button's title:

```
- (IBAction)startButtonTouchUpInside:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self doSomeStuff];
    sender.titleLabel.text = @"Clicked";
}
```

However when I test the app and click on the `UIButton`, the`UIButtons` title changes for a fraction of a second before being reverted to title as provided in the Stroyboard interface builder.

Is this normal?

Comment: That was indeed the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [apple docs of `titleLabel`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIButton/titleLabel)

> Do not use the label object to set the text color or the shadow color. Instead, use the setTitleColor:forState: and setTitleShadowColor:forState: methods of this class to make those changes.

Similarly for text you should use `setTitle:forState:`

```
[sender.titleLabel setTitle:@"Clicked" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```